# How to display both data in Edittext without losing one of them?

Tags: java, android

I have two Edittexts in MainActivity: `etFrom` and `etTo`.
When clicked `etFrom` goes to `ListFrom` activity and `etTo` to `ListTo` activity.`ListFrom` and `ListTo` activities contain Listview and after choosing an item it comes back to Main activity and displays results in edittexts. I use `MainActivity.putExtra("To",v);` and `etTo.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("To"));` to get data from an activity.

After clicking on first edittext, choosing an item from Listview and coming back to Main Activity, when I do the same for second edittext the first edittext becomes empty. And the same when I do first one, second one becomes empty.[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PgxD.jpg) [Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wulp.jpg)

ListTo Code

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_to);


    etSearchTo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearchTo);
    listViewTo=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewTo);


    initList();
    listViewTo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String v="";
            Intent intent=new Intent(ListTo.this,SearchRide.class);
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    v = items[0];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    v = items[1];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    v = items[2];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    v = items[3];
                    break;
                case 4:
                    v = items[4];
                    break;
                case 5:
                    v = items[5];
                    break;
            }

            intent.putExtra("To",v);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

ListFrom Code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_from);

    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewFrom);
    editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etsearchFrom);





    initList();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String v="";
            Intent intent=new Intent(ListFrom.this,SearchRide.class);
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    v = items[0];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    v = items[1];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    v = items[2];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    v = items[3];
                    break;
                case 4:
                    v = items[4];
                    break;
                case 5:
                    v = items[5];
                    break;
            }

            intent.putExtra("From",v);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
```

SearchRide as Main Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_ride);





    etDate=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDate);
    TextView tFrom=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tFrom);
    TextView tTo=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tTo);
    etFrom=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFrom);
    etTo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTo);
    Button bSearch=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bSearch);
    ImageView iplussign=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iplussign);
    ImageView iminussign=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iminussign);
    final TextView tNumber=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tNumber);

    etTo.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("To"));


    tNumber.setText(String.valueOf(p));
    iplussign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(p<=9) {
                p++;
                tNumber.setText(String.valueOf(p));
            }
        }
    });
    iminussign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(p>=2) {
                p--;
                tNumber.setText(String.valueOf(p));
            }
        }
    });

    etFrom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent ListFrom=new Intent(SearchRide.this,ListFrom.class);
            startActivity(ListFrom);
        }
    });
    etFrom.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("From"));

    etTo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent ToList =new Intent(SearchRide.this,ListTo.class);
            startActivity(ToList);
        }
    });
    etTo.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("To"));

    etDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatePickerDialog dialog= new DatePickerDialog(SearchRide.this,R.style.MyDatePickerStyle,listener,calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

}
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: Please post your onCreate, onStart and onResume methods

Comment: Posted. I don't have OnStart and OnResume methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use startActivityForResult() to start ListFrom and ListTo Activities and the receive the result from these activities in OnActivityResult() method.

SearchRide as Main Activity code:

```
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_ride);

                etDate=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDate);
                TextView tFrom=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tFrom);
                TextView tTo=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tTo);
                etFrom=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFrom);
                etTo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTo);
                Button bSearch=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bSearch);
                ImageView iplussign=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iplussign);
                ImageView iminussign=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iminussign);
                final TextView tNumber=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tNumber);

                tNumber.setText(String.valueOf(p));
                iplussign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(p<=9) {
                            p++;
                            tNumber.setText(String.valueOf(p));
                        }
                    }
                });

                iminussign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(p>=2) {
                            p--;
                            tNumber.setText(String.valueOf(p));
                        }
                    }
                });

                etFrom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent ListFrom = new Intent(SearchRide.this,ListFrom.class);
                        startActivityForResult(ListFrom,0);
                    }
                });

                etTo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent ToList = new Intent(SearchRide.this,ListTo.class);
                        startActivityForResult(ToList,1);
                    }
                });

                etDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        DatePickerDialog dialog= new DatePickerDialog(SearchRide.this,R.style.MyDatePickerStyle,listener,calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                        dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                if (requestCode == 0) {
                    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                        etFrom.setText(data.getStringExtra("From"));
                    }
                } else if (requestCode == 1) {
                    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                        etTo.setText(data.getStringExtra("To"));
                    }

                }}
```

ListFrom code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_from);

listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewFrom);
editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etsearchFrom);

initList();
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String v="";
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                v = items[0];
                break;
            case 1:
                v = items[1];
                break;
            case 2:
                v = items[2];
                break;
            case 3:
                v = items[3];
                break;
            case 4:
                v = items[4];
                break;
            case 5:
                v = items[5];
                break;
        }
    Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("From",v);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();

    }
});
```

ListTo code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_to);

etSearchTo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearchTo);
listViewTo=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewTo);

initList();
listViewTo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String v="";
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                v = items[0];
                break;
            case 1:
                v = items[1];
                break;
            case 2:
                v = items[2];
                break;
            case 3:
                v = items[3];
                break;
            case 4:
                v = items[4];
                break;
            case 5:
                v = items[5];
                break;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("To",v);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: "App keeps Stopping"

Comment: copy and paste the MainActivity from above, the app should not keep stopping

Comment: I have edited the code, please try it now and tell if it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do. Put both from and to values as extra when starting an activity and return them both as result. This way you will be able to remember it. I am assuming you just do not want to use static variables.

```
// in ListTo activity
intent.putExtra("To",v);
intent.putExtra("From", getIntent().getStringExtra("From"));

// in ListFrom activity
intent.putExtra("From",v);
intent.putExtra("To", getIntent().getStringExtra("To"));

// in Main activity
etTo.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("To"));
etFrom.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("From"));

// when starting ListFrom activity
Intent ListFrom=new Intent(SearchRide.this,ListFrom.class);
intent.putExtra("From", getIntent().getStringExtra("From"));
intent.putExtra("To", getIntent().getStringExtra("To"));
startActivity(ListFrom);

// when starting ListTo activity
Intent ToList =new Intent(SearchRide.this,ListTo.class);
intent.putExtra("From", getIntent().getStringExtra("From"));
intent.putExtra("To", getIntent().getStringExtra("To"));
startActivity(ToList);
```

PS: I have not tested the above code. You can experience null pointer errors, but it should give you the general idea.